# Win32API/Win drivers: How to detect if file is accessed

Tags: security, winapi, driver, honeypot

I would like to create something like "file honeypot" on Windows OS.

The problem I would like to answer is this:
I need to detect that file is accessed (Malware wants to read file to send it over internet) so I can react to it. But I do not know how exacly tackle this thing.

1. I can periodically test file - Do not like this sollution. Would like some event driven without need to bother processor every few ms. But could work if file is huge enought so it cannot be read between checks.
2. I could exclusively open file myselve and somehow detect if file is accessed. But I have no idea how to do this thing.

Any idea about how to resolve this issue effectively? Maybe creating specialized driver could help but I have little experience in this.

Thanks

Comment: If you want straight WinAPI, you could check out `ReadDirectoryChangesW`(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx), or if you can use .NET there's the `FileSystemWatcher` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Would either of those help?

Comment: Anti-malware software uses the same techniques as malware.  It patches the operating system to intercept the low-level operating system calls.  Not making the cure worse than the disease requires much more than one programmer can ever accomplish.  Or one Q+A site.

Comment: @txtechhelp Both of your suggestions can only respond to **changes**. Read attempts cannot be trapped. In fact, none of those solutions can actually *trap* anything; they merely observe, and are informed about changes **after the fact**.

Comment: @txtechhelp: For a honeypot that would be fine, but it isn't really true. A filter driver can trap and block or modify anything, including read attempts.

Comment: Good notes on that for the OP and this question! Thanks for the catch; I agree a filter driver would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking (and possibly preventing) filesystem access on Windows is accomplished using filesystem filter drivers. But you must be aware that kernel-mode code (rootkits etc) can bypass the filter driver stack and send the request directly to the filesystem. In this case only the filesystem driver itself can log or intercept access.

Comment: That is actually good point. I do not worry about targeted attack at this instance. So the question is how much common is for malware to use kernel mode driver to read and steal sensitive files.

Comment: @Mildar this question is quite subjective. There exist some number of rootkits (i.e. malware that works in kernel mode or even lower), but it's not high. You can discuss this question in more details on http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that what you're writing is a relatively simple honeypot. The integrity of the system on which you're running has not been compromised, there is no rootkit or filter driver installation by malware and there is no process running that can implement avoidance or anti-avoidance measures.

The most likely scenario I can think of is that a server process running on the computer is subject to some kind of external control which would allow files containing sensitive data to be read remotely. It could be a web server, a mail server, an FTP server or something else but I assume nothing else on the computer has been compromised. And the task at hand is to watch particular files and see if anything is reading them.

With these assumptions a file system watcher will not help. It can monitor parts of the system for the creation of new files or modification or deletion of existing ones, but as far as I know it cannot monitor for read only access.

The only event-driven mechanism I am aware of is a filter driver. This is a specialised piece of driver software that can be inserted into the driver chain and monitor access to files. With the constraints above, it is a reliable solution to the problem at the cost of being quite hard to write.

If a polling mechanism is sufficient then I can see two avenues. One is to try to lock the file exclusively, which will fail if it is open. This is easy, but slow.

The other is to monitor the open file handles. I know it can be done because I know programs that do it, but I can't tell you how without some research.

If my assumptions are wrong, please edit your question and provide additional information.